# Issue in using swift files into my objC project

Tags: ios, swift

I've to use some .swift file into my objctiveC project.when I'm trying to add the swift files into bundle, the productodule-swift.h file not getting generated instead its generating bridging header file.I've changed my project settings DEFINES_MODULE to YES and PRODUCT_MODULE to myprojectnameModule...but no use...is there anything I'm doing wrong.please suggest me...thanks in advance

Comment: It's probably just being buggy, have you tried the basics, i.e: clean project, restart Xcode, restart machine, etc.

Comment: Yeah...I've done all the things like quiting xcode and reopening,restarting the machine...No change:(

Comment: Which developer preview? Also, have you tried doing a fresh project and see-ing if the header is generated?

Comment: Yeah,I've tried with the other projects created in xcode6,xcode5.1.1(created in xcode5.1.1 opened in xcode6)...Every project creating the bridging header file only.I'm using Mac 10.9.3,xcode6 beta2.

Comment: You do realize that it's 100% automatic right? There's no button or switch you click to make it generate the swift header. Have you tried setting DEFINES_MODULE to NO and PRODUCT_MODULE to empty string? Also, the import line should be `#import "MyProductName-Swift.h"`

Comment: Yes,I do.As far my understanding,The "MyProductName-Swift.h" file should get generated automatically when I add a .swift file into the bundle and it should contain list of class names that are implmented in swift file which can be used in any objC File with import statement.In my case its generating projectName-bridging-header.h file.Is there any misconception? If so please let me know and one thing I want to know is how myProductName-Swift.h is coded(syntax of a swift class name so that I can make a try to create a new header with same name and dump the code excactly how it is)

Comment: Yess!!I found the mistake that I was doing..I've deleted the bridging-header file thinkig its unnecessary in a misconception that either of MyProductName-Swift.h,MyProductName-Bridging-header.h,only one gets generated.But both are generated when importing a .swift file,one is visible -briding-header.h file and the othe is invisible -swift.h file.and the settings DEFINES_MODULE should be YES and PRODUCT_MODULE should be module name.Thanks @theMonster....happy coding..

Comment: Make sure that you make that the solution to your question so others can benefit from your findings :)

Answer (score 1):

1. MyProductName-Bridging-header.h,MyProductName-Swift.h both are generated when importing a .swift file for the first time.
2. MyProductName-Swift.h file is not visible but exists in project.**Never Delete MyProductName-bridging-header.h file**
3. Settings DEFINES_MODULE should be **YES** and PRODUCT_MODULE should be **MyProductName**.
4. Add **# import "MyProductName-Swift.h"** in your objective-c class.